# In ODI file to table load-in .bad and .error file not created

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

In ODI 12c I have file to table load. If I have correct data in file then data loaded into the table. If I have wrong data(eg for emp_name I have length 30 but in file I have length 40) then mapping is error out but .bad file and .error file is not created.
Km used: file to sql

Please let me how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Error and log files will be getting created on the Work schema directory. Did you tried checking that directory or you can help me with the flow in operator so i can check and help you with detailed info.[image]

Comment: yes. I checked in the work schema directory. I am using lkm file to SQL, should I need to use any other KM to get .error file

Comment: During LKM selection there are few options available down there. e.g delete temporary objects . You can refer to that you may have mark something true or false which is deleting the .bad and log files.